# How do I add more subreddits/keywords to this reddit bot code?

Tags: python, bots, reddit

I found this reddit bot code on GitHub, it literally is just a comment bot.

https://github.com/yashar1/reddit-comment-bot

I know little about Python, so i tried to doctor the code to have multiple subreddits and keywords, adding these:

```
keywords = ["hello", "okay"]
subreddits = ["test", "bottest"]

    for comment in r.subreddit(any(subreddits)).comments(limit=100):
        if any(keywords) in comment.body and comment.id not in comments_replied_to 
and comment.author != r.user.me():
```

This code doesn't seem to work, mostly due to my limited knowledge of Python. I want the bot to scan multiple subreddits and search for multiple keywords.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include multiple subreddits like so.

```
subreddits_list = "test+bottest"
subreddits = r.subreddit(subreddits_list)
```

To check for multiple keywords, you can use.

```
keywords = ["hello", "okay"]
for comment in subreddits.comments(limit=100):
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword in comment.body and comment.id not in comments_replied_to and comment.author != r.user.me():
```